# what's the reason for file lock odd behavior only with few windows server

Tags: c#, windows-services

I have C# console app which runs as windows service and running with `NT Service` account. As soon as service runs a database file (`sqlite`) is created within user file location

`C:\Users\XXX\AppData\Local\TimeSeries.db`

In one of the production server when I am checking `day 1` the file used by same app exe `test.exe` and same `PID` I am seeing 2 entries. I am NOT sure why, but things are working as expected and data `read/write` is proper.

[image]

After `few days run` I am start getting `TimeSeries.db` file lock issue and `read/write` NOT working and at this point `3` entries for same service with same PID `1736`.

Question is why it's increase one more entries, but service is running with only one instance and due to this file lock occurs. Why and how to resolve this issue.

Note - This problem not with all production server? Here the problem occurs with server is a big server having multi core.

[image]

Code:

```
public class LiteContext
{
    public LiteDatabase Database { get; }

    public LiteContext()
    {
        Database = new LiteDatabase("TimeSeries.db");
    }
}


  public class LiteDbResultWrite
  {
    private readonly LiteDatabase _liteDb;

    public LiteDbResultPacketService(LiteContext liteContext)
    {
        _liteDb = liteContext.Database;
    }

    public Task<Guid> Insert(Result result)
    {
        try
        {
            var liteCollection = _liteDb.GetCollection<Result>("Result");
            return Task.FromResult(liteCollection.Insert(result).AsGuid);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new Guid());
        }

    }
}
```

I guess I am missing `IDisposable` for `LiteDbResultWrite` ? Is this correct?

Comment: At a guess someone is forgetting to close/dispose the file, we don't know without seeing the code

Comment: @Charlieface. Thank for your reply. I have added code in my question. Do you think I am missing `IDisposable` for `LiteDbResultWrite` class here ?

Comment: By the looks of things, yes, `_liteDb` needs disposing

Comment: @Charlieface. like this? ` public void Dispose()
        {
            _liteDb?.Dispose();
        }`

Comment: You need to make sure it actually gets called though. Use a `using` block

Comment: Could you please let me know what these all entries above in image. Why sometime 2 or 3 entries as all having same PID